# Python: function as attribute of class, not method

Tags: python

I'd like to have attribute of class, which stores some function, but this function is not method of the class, it will be called later by other component completely out of scope of the class itself, so class is just container for the attribute with function. But call of this function fails with `TypeError: unbound method`

```
def f(x): print x
class A:
    not_method = f
A.not_method(10)
```

Is there any way to suppress this error? The obvious way is to store function warped by some data object, like tuple, but it seems not so elegant.

```
def f(x): print x
class A:
    not_method = (f,)
A.not_method[0](10)
```

Proposed solution with `@staticmethod` is not so cool, cause:
- formally the attribute is not a method at all, it's just attribute with some external function
- `@staticmethod` decorator does not work with attribute assignment

Comment: Can you explain your use case better? Sounds like you need to define a static method.

Comment: Do you just want to suppress that error ?

Comment: Which Python version is it? It works perfectly fine in Python 3-x.

Comment: 1) No, it's not the method at all, formally speaking, it's just link to some function which will be called completely out of scope of the class, so should be considered as data from class standpoint. 2) Yes, just supress error 3) Python 2.7, if it works in 3.0 it's ok, i'll just leave workaround for 2.7 and that's all.